# Android Redrawing an image to new position when the screen is touched

Tags: android

I am trying to write a small android app that redraws an image everytime the screen is touched.

I expected the image to be redrawn to the new `x,y` coordinates provided by `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` when I override the `onTouch(Event)` method in an activity.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I presume, you'd be having the Bitmap object for the image.

You could call the onDraw() method from the onTouch() method, to draw the bitmap. Here's a code sample which shows the overridden onDraw() method:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
      { 
         canvas.drawBitmap(imgBitmap, x, y, null);
      }
```

x,y are the new co-ordinates of the touch. imgBitmap is the Bitmap object for the image. You can update the instance variables x and y in the onTouch() method.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: This is what I am doing but the image doesn't get redrawn when i touch the screen

Comment: Are you calling invalidate() to refresh the draw cycle?

Comment: public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
     {
    
         switch(event.getAction()){
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
          int x = (int) event.getX();
          int y = (int) event.getY();
          Rect rect = new Rect();
          rect.set(50, 50, x, y);
          canvas.drawBitmap(bob565, null, rect, null);
         
          break;
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          invalidate();
          break;
         }

         return true;
     }

Comment: how do you get hold of the canvas in the onTouchEvent() method? All your draw calls should be in the onDraw(Canvas canvas) method.